# How effective are economic sanctions on Russia?

Tags: inflation, central-banking, sanctions, russia

Things like "banning Russia from SWIFT" sound devastating, but then we find out that actually it is a ban on some (not all) Russian banks. So, do the sanctions imposed by the West and the pro-western countries actually hurt Russian economy, or do the Russians find the ways to make them painless?

Answer (score 2):

Some sanctions can be evaded and some others are just political symbolism but overall the sanctions do hurt Russian economy.

In January 2022 Russian economy grew at about 6% (see [Statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1009056/gdp-growth-rate-russia/)). After the war and sanctions the The Institute of International Finance predicts a 15% contraction for Russia (as Reported by [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/four-weeks-war-scar-russias-economy-2022-03-24/)).

This effectively reverses 15 years of Russian economic growth, meaning that in one year Russia in economic terms will get back to 2006 (see picture below). That’s quite a lot, it’s worse than the economic impact of recent pandemic on some countries.  This is based partially on forecasts which are not 100% accurate but I reckon that even in best case scenario Russia will experience at least 8-10% contraction. However, in worst case it could contract even by 20% perhaps even more.

[image]